# Array, java - sort specific/dynamic part

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I'm stuck at sorting an array (part of course, not allowed to use methods).

Array with random generated numbers should be sorted and printed:
Even (ascending - Odd (descending)

From: 830 281 380 162 679 587 944 143 940 862 546 730

To: 162 380 546 730 830 862 940 944 - 679 587 281 143

I've managed to separate even and odds and sort the even ones but get stuck at sorting odds.

Realize I'm probably not doing it the most effective way by separate sorting in two different parts but would really appreciate if you could point out what's wrong.

Idea was to count odd and even numbers and use these numbers to know where in the array to loop sorting but that's were in failing on odd part.

Sorry about frakencode...

```
int[] arr = new int[amountRandom];
        for (int i = 0; i < amountRandom; i++)
        {
            arr[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 1000); 
        }


int checkEvenOdd;
        int evenAmount = 0; 
        int oddAmount = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
        {
            checkEvenOdd = arr[i] % 2;

            if(checkEvenOdd == 0)
            {
                evenAmount++;
            }
            else
            {
                oddAmount++;
            }
        }

int arrLeft = 0;
        int arrRight;
        arrRight = arr.length - 1;

        while(arrLeft < arrRight) {
            while(arr[arrLeft] % 2 == 0 && arrLeft < arrRight) {
                arrLeft++;
            }
            while(arr[arrRight] % 2 != 0 && arrLeft < arrRight) {
                arrRight--;
            }
            if(arrLeft < arrRight) {
                int x = arr[arrLeft];
                arr[arrLeft] = arr[arrRight];
                arr[arrRight] = x;

                arrLeft++;
                arrRight--;
            }
        }

int i, j, minValue, minIndex, temp = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < evenAmount; i++) {
        minValue = arr[i];                      
        minIndex = i;
        for (j = i; j < evenAmount; j++) {  
            if (arr[j] < minValue) {
                minValue = arr[j];
                minIndex = j;
            }
        }
        if (minValue < arr[i]) {        
            temp = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[minIndex];
            arr[minIndex] = temp;
        }
    }

int maxValue, maxIndex, temp2 = 0;
    **for (i = evenAmount; i < amountRandom; i++)** {
        maxValue = arr[i];                      
        maxIndex = i;
        for (j = i; j > oddAmount; j++) {   
            if (arr[j] > maxValue) {
                maxValue = arr[j];
                maxIndex = j;
                }
            }
            if (maxValue > arr[i]) {        
                temp2 = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[maxIndex];
                arr[maxIndex] = temp2;
                }
            }
```

Answer (score -2):

Check out here all kinds of [sorting algorithms](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sorting-algorithms/).

Anyway, you do not have to hard code a sorting algorithm because Java has its own pre-made algorithms that you can use: [Java methods ready to use](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/arrays-sort-in-java-with-examples/)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour], visit the [help], and especially read [answer].  Answers containing only links to outside resources are strongly discouraged as the links will eventually go bad (404) making your answer useless.  Also, if you copy anything into your answer from another site, you are required to attribute the source.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Taking a course and we're not allowed to use the methods unfortunately.

And thanks for linking to sorting algorithms, I've seen them it's the application that's my problem. Specifically how to only loop over the last part of odd numbers:
for (i = evenAmount; i < amountRandom; i++)